# MySQL slow query log, query_time is long but lock_time is short

Tags: mysql

Recently, I find that our MySQL database is very slow when it execute a query or update. After I read the slow query log, I find that a simple update need very a lot of time.

Here is the slow query *log*:

```
# Time: 2021-08-31T07:46:49.876145Z
# User@Host: root[root] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id:  3407
# Query_time: 244.919185  Lock_time: 0.000261 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1630396009;
UPDATE `submissions` SET `result`='JG',`updated_at`='2021-08-31 15:42:44' WHERE `id` = 3570934;
```

> I don't know why the `query_time` is so long but the `lock_time` is
> short. If you can give me some possible reason, I will be very
> appreciative.

Comment: Odd. What version of MySQL? (from `SELECT VERSION()`)

Comment: the mysql version 5.7.29

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE submissions`

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'submissions';